# Tabnine Extension was unable to download its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-code

please complete the following information:

**Tabnine Extension was unable to download its dependencies. Please check your internet connection. If you use a proxy server, please visit https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not a solution, but it may help someone.

I met the same problem with a remote ssh Linux machine, and I tried the following solutions:

- remove vscode-server extension directory under `~/.vscode-server` then reinstall
- set http proxy both vscode settings and linux environment (enabled before)
- downgrade tabnine version
- ...

none of these worked.

But I noticed that if I cancel the proxy, the pop-up error takes longer.
Of course, the proxy works fine. I guess something went wrong with the network.

So, I **switched my proxy to another region**, and it worked.
I guess tabnine block my proxy ip for some re

So, the suggestion is:

1. change your network provider, make sure it can access tabnine.
2. Or set up http proxy in vscode settings, and switch to another one if it does not working.
3. for vscode remote user, make the proxy settings modified on remote host.
4. delete extension configs and reinstall, for vscode remote, delete `vsocde-server`

Comment: "switched my proxy to another region" it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install 3.2.8. it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).